# Why I can't ping container by its hostname, from an external machine, while using macvlan?

Tags: docker, networking

I am creating a macvlan with this conf:

```
sudo docker network create -d macvlan \
    --subnet=192.168.4.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.4.1 \
    -o macvlan_mode=bridge \
    -o parent=eth0 macvlan70
```

Then I run an alpine image using:

```
docker run --net=macvlan70 --hostname=thehost --ip=192.168.4.17 -it  alpine /bin/sh
```

*At this moment I moved to another machine in LAN - host can't connect with Macvlan containers without a bridge.*

I can `ping 192.168.4.17` with success. But `ping thehost` will not result. In the router admin page the ip `192.168.4.17` is recognized but without the hostname associated.

Comment: do you see `thehost` from inside the container as hostname?

Comment: @Edwin yes. `hostname` will return `thehost`

Comment: then from the docs: `Even in host network mode a container has its own UTS namespace by default. As such --hostname is allowed in host network mode and will only change the hostname inside the container` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Comment: @jcardosovtl Were you expecting Docker's `--hostname` to somehow propagate to your network's DNS?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart my first guess was that docker managed that automatically. But perhaps that's not true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's said in the docker [docs](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run), the user-defined hostname is not available from outside of the container.

> Even in host network mode a container has its own UTS namespace by default. As such --hostname is allowed in host network mode and will only change the hostname inside the container